# Kotlin Gradle DSL cpp-library source wildcard

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, source-sets

Gradle offers a plugin which compiler cpp-library

build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    `cpp-library`
}
library {
    targetMachines.add(machines.windows.x86_64)
    linkage.set(listOf(Linkage.SHARED))
    source.from("src/main/cpp/*.txt")
}
```

I am getting below output

```
:compileDebugCpp NO-SOURCE
```

How to use the `source.from` to specify custom file extension like `*.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution my self

I need to put the source in the compilation task as below

```
tasks.withType(CppCompile::class.java).configureEach {
    source.from(fileTree("${project.rootDir}/${project.name}/src/main/cpp").matching {
        include("*.txt")
    })
}
```

this allow the gradle C++ compiler task compile `.txt` files instead of `.cpp` file

So in case if I want to compiler `fortran` then I can put `*.f` or `*.f90`